# Start Hadoop 50075 Port is not resolved

Tags: hadoop

I have installed Hadoop in my system, Jobtracker : localhost:50030/jobtracker.jsp is working fine but localhost:50075/ host is not resolved. Can anybody help my what is the problem in my Ubuntu system. Below check my code-site.xml configuration :

```
<configuration>
     <property>
         <name>fs.default.name</name>
         <value>hdfs://localhost:9000</value>
     </property>
</configuration>
```

Comment: What do you expect to start on port 50075?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Check your port configurations. Here is a list of hadoop daemon configurable parameters

dfs.http.address: The address and the base port where the dfs namenode web ui will listen on. If the port is 0 then the server will start on a free port.

The default for the name node is usually set to port 50070, so try localhost:50070.

http://hadoop.apache.org/common/docs/r0.20.2/hdfs-default.html

I think you mean core-site.xml (not code-site.xml). The fs.default.name configuration here does not determine the location of the hadoop web ui/dashboard. This is the port used by data nodes to communicate with the name node.

Answer (score 6):

never seen 50075 before, but 50070 is the local NameNode, I suggest you format the NameNode to have a try:

```
rm -r /tmp/hadoop-*;
bin/hadoop namenode -format;
./bin/start-all.sh
```

Comment: After cleaning up the /tmp/hadoop*  directory my name node is working fine.