# http://localhost:50070 does not work HADOOP

Tags: hadoop

I already installed Hadoop on my machine "Ubuntu 13.05" and now I have an error when browsing localhost:50070 the browser says that the page does not exist.

Answer (score 120):

Since Hadoop 3.0.0 - Alpha 1 there was a Change in the port configuration:

`http://localhost:50070`

was moved to

`http://localhost:9870`

see https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/HDFS-9427

Answer (score 64):

port 50070 changed to 9870 in 3.0.0-alpha1

In fact, lots of others ports changed too. Look:

```
Namenode ports: 50470 --> 9871, 50070 --> 9870, 8020 --> 9820
Secondary NN ports: 50091 --> 9869, 50090 --> 9868
Datanode ports: 50020 --> 9867, 50010 --> 9866, 50475 --> 9865, 50075 --> 9864
```

[Source](https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/HDFS-9427)

Comment: Very helpful information. I kept looking for reasons why port 50070 was not working, and this list will no doubt save me many hours of frustration.

Comment: You are my life-saver. I wonder why many tutorials out there do not mention anything about this. They just told me to access port 50070 without checking which ports are running or something. Thanks again.

Answer (score 9):

First, check that java processes that are running using "jps". If you are in a pseudo-distributed mode you must have the following proccesses:

- Namenode
- Jobtracker
- Tasktracker
- Datanode
- SecondaryNamenode

If you are missing any, use the restart commands:

```
$HADOOP_INSTALL/bin/stop-all.sh
$HADOOP_INSTALL/bin/start-all.sh
```

It can also be because you haven't open that port on the machine:

```
iptables -A INPUT -p tcp --dport 50070 -j ACCEPT
```

Comment: You can check whether the port is open but inaccessible with: `ss -ltp | grep 50070`.  If the port is not there, you need the stop-all/start-all and so on.  If it IS listed you probably have a firewall problem and it's IP tables to the rescue.

Comment: Port 50070 is run by the namenode, so actually that is technically the only one entry in your jps listing that is essential.  It turns out that my namenode was unhappy.  I looked in the log file for the namenode (`$HADOOP_HOME/logs/hadoop-*-namenode-*.log`) that showed that the filesystem had become corrupted somehow.  Erasing the data and reformatting fixed that.

Answer (score 6):

- step 1 : bin/stop-all.sh
- step 2 : bin/hadoop namenode -format
- step 3 : bin/start-all.sh

Answer (score 6):

For recent hadoop versions (I'm using 2.7.1)

The start\stop scripts are located in the `sbin` folder. The scripts are:

- ./sbin/start-dfs.sh
- ./sbin/stop-dfs.sh
- ./sbin/start-yarn.sh
- ./sbin/stop-yarn.sh

I didn't have to do anything with **yarn** though to get the **NameNodeServer** instance running.

Now my mistake was that I didn't format the **NameNodeServer** HDFS.

```
bin/hdfs namenode -format
```

I'm not quite sure what that does at the moment but it obviously prepares the space on which the **NameNodeServer** will use to operate.

Answer (score 2):

If you can open the http://localhost:8088/cluster but can't open http://localhost:50070/. Maybe datanode didn't start-up or namenode didn't formate.

Hadoop version 2.6.4

- step 1:

check whether your namenode has been formated, if not type:

```
$ stop-all.sh
$ /path/to/hdfs namenode -format
$ start-all.sh
```

- step 2:

check your namenode tmp file path, to see in `/tmp`, if the namenode directory is in `/tmp`, you need set tmp path in `core-site.xml`, because every time when you reboot or start your machine, the files in `/tmp` will be removed, you need set a tmp dir path.

add the following to it.

```
<property>
    <name>hadoop.tmp.dir</name>
    <value>/path/to/hadoop/tmp</value>
</property>
```

- step 3:

check step 2, stop hadoop and remove the namenode tmp dir in `/tmp`, then type `/path/to/hdfs namenode -format`, and start the hadoop. The is also a `tmp` dir in `$HADOOP_HOME`

If all the above don't help, please comment below!

Answer (score 1):

There is a similar question and answer at: [Start Hadoop 50075 Port is not resolved](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11063156/start-hadoop-50075-port-is-not-resolved)

Take a look at your core-site.xml file to determine which port it is set to. If 0, it will randomly pick a port, so be sure to set one.

Answer (score 1):

Try

```
namenode -format
start-all.sh
stop-all.sh
jps
```

see `namenode` and `datanode` are running and browse

```
localhost:50070
```

If `localhost:50070` is still not working, then you need to allows ports. So, check

```
netstat -anp | grep 50070
```

Answer (score 1):

Enable the port in your system it is for CentOS 7
flow the commands below

1.firewall-cmd --get-active-zones

2.firewall-cmd --zone=dmz --add-port=50070/tcp --permanent

3.firewall-cmd --zone=public --add-port=50070/tcp --permanent

4.firewall-cmd --zone=dmz --add-port=9000/tcp --permanent

5.firewall-cmd --zone=public --add-port=9000/tcp --permanent
 6.firewall-cmd --reload

Answer (score 1):

After installing and configuring Hadoop, you can quickly run the command
netstat -tulpn

to find the ports open. In the new version of Hadoop 3.1.3 the ports are as follows:-

localhost:8042  Hadoop,
localhost:9870  HDFS, 
localhost:8088  YARN

Answer (score 0):

First all need to do is start hadoop nodes and Trackers, simply by typing 
start-all.sh on ur terminal.
To check all the trackers and nodes are started write 'jps' command.
if everything is fine and working,
go to your browser type the following url
http://localhost:50070

Comment: everything is fine and working:--   146103 Jps
143205 ResourceManager
142936 SecondaryNameNode
142601 NameNode
143374 NodeManager
142734 DataNode
but http://localhost:50070 show nothing  not able to i don't want to format namenode while fixing the problem

Answer (score 0):

if you are running and old version of Hadoop (hadoop 1.2) you got an error because http://localhost:50070/dfshealth.html does'nt exit. Check http://localhost:50070/dfshealth.jsp which works !