# http://localhost:50070/ web UI doesn't work

Tags: hadoop

I am using latest version of Hadoop & java as well.
After configuring all the files for respective building blocks of hadoop (HDFS, mapreduce, yarn), I formatted the namenode and send the below command

> sbin/start-all.sh

Post the enter, I typed in firefox browser http://localhost:50070/. I get 'unable to connect' error.

How do i access the Web UI for hadoop.

NOTE: I am currently using Ubuntu 18.04

Comment: Does this answer your question? [http://localhost:50070 does not work HADOOP](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19641326/http-localhost50070-does-not-work-hadoop)

Answer (score 6):

The later version of Hadoop i.e. 3.x.x; the 50070 has changed to 9870.
So, type in the browser

localhost:9870